# Error:Failed to complete Gradle execution. Cause: No space left on device

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

When I try to run/build my Android Studio Project I'm getting the below error.

```
Error:Failed to complete Gradle execution. 
Cause: No space left on device
```

I'm using Linux enviroment.
I tried emptying the /temp directory with the following command, but was of no help.`find /tmp -ctime +10 -exec rm -rf {} +`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot searching I got the blow command, which solved the problem for me.

```
sudo mount -o remount,size=2G /tmp
```

Comment: Context: this command extends the size limit of the tmp folder